# Eigenvalue of a matrix that the sum of each column is equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.

**i)** Prove that if the sum of each row of $A$ equals $s$, then $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

**ii)** Prove that if the sum of each column of $A$ equals $s$, then $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

The first question isn't a problem, but I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour trying to find the answer to the second one. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: You can use a fact about eigenvalues of $A$ and eigenvalues of $A^T$.

Comment: Thanks! Got me on the right path!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment above: the key is to note that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues.