# Sum of the columns of a matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is not homework; it is self studying. I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089474/163751) . However, my question is when the columns sum to one; this means the matrix has a eigenvalue of one. Obviously, the question in the link applies to this too. I was just wondering if my solution is correct. If it is not please suggest a hint (if possible) without revealing the answer.

Assume no knowledge that the eigenvalues of ${A}$ and ${A^t}$ are the same.

Assume we know the following facts based on previous solved problems:

1) sum of the rows equals ${s}$ implies 
${A}$ has an eigenvalue that is ${s}$.

2) $T$ is the operator for matrix $A$ and $T'(\phi) :=\phi • T$ is the dual operator with matrix $A^t$

3) given a basis of dual vectors for $V'$, $\exists$ a basis of  $V$ such that the basis of dual vectors is the dual basis to that basis of $V$.

Consider ${A^t}$, since the rows sum to 1, ${A^t}$ has an eigenvalue 1, thus $\exists{\psi}$ a corresponding eigenvector of ${A^t}$. Extend $\psi$ to a basis for $V'$ : $\psi, {\phi_2}, ... {\phi_n}$. Thus there exists a basis  $v_{\psi},v_2,...v_n$  of $V$ such that $\psi, {\phi_2},...{\phi_n}$ is its (ordered) dual basis.

Thus using the definition of $T'$ and dual basis: 
$T'(\psi)(v_{\psi}) = {\psi} • T(v_{\psi}) = \psi(v_{\psi}) = 1 $

We seek to show:  the definition of dual basis and $\psi •T(v_{\psi})=1 \implies T(v_{\psi})=v_{\psi}$

Assume $T(v_{\psi}) = w \neq v_{\psi}$ and, $w$ is linearly independent of $v_{\psi}$ and $\psi(w) = 1$. Then $T$ doesn't annihilate $span(v_{\psi}, w)$ , but does annihilate $v_2,...,v_n$.  However $w, v_{\psi}, v_2, ...v_n$ can't be linearly independent since dimension of $V$ is $n$. Since, $w$ is linearly independent  of $v_{\psi}$. We can conclude that $w \in span(v_2, ..., v_n)$. Thus $\psi(w) =0$

$\implies T(v_{\psi}) = v_{\psi}$

■.

Something feels slightly off with this proof. Especially, the conclusion that $T(v_{\psi})=v_{\psi}$.

**Updated Attempt (with help from 'simple example' in the comments)**

Assume just bullet point 1 and 2 above:

Since the columns of $A^t$ sum to 1, $T'$ has an eigenvalue of 1. Thus $\exists\psi \in V'$ that is an eigenvector of $T'$ with an eigenvalue of 1.

Thus for $\forall v \in V$: $T'(\psi)(v) = \psi(v) \implies  \psi * T(v) = \psi(v)$  (definition of $T'$)

4) $\psi *T(v) - \psi(v) = 0$

5) $\psi(T(v) - v) = 0 $ (linearity)

6) $\psi((T - I_V)v) = 0$ (distributive property of linear maps)

In the non-trivial case, $\psi$ is not injective since it is a map from $V$ onto $F$ with $dim V_F \gt dim F_F =1$, where $F$ is the base field.
Thus $null(\psi) \neq \{0\}$.

To satisfy point "6)",  $range(T-I_V) \subseteq null(\psi)$. Thus $dim(range(T-I_V)) \le dim(null(\psi)) \lt dim(V)$ ($\psi \neq 0_V$)

$dim(range(T-I_V)) \lt dim(V) \implies T-I_V$ is NOT surjective and thus 1 is an eigenvalue of $T$. $\Box$

To cover the trivial case: If $dim(V)=dim(F)=1$, then $\psi$ is injective, thus $null(\psi)=\{0\} \implies (T-I_V) = 0_V \implies T-I_v$ is not surjective

**Verification on Simple Example**

$A = [[0, -1], [1, 2]], \psi=[1, 1]$, where $A$ is the matrix for $T$,
and $A^t$ is the matrix for $T'$

Let $\phi=[1, 0]$ and $\psi,\phi$ form a basis for $V'$.
Thus we can find a basis of $V$ this is dual to: $v_{\psi}, v_{\phi}$,
$v_{\psi}=[0, 1]^t, v_{\phi}=[1, -1]^t$.

$A^t\psi^t = \psi^t \implies \psi$ is an eigenvector of $A^t$ as desired

Following the conclusion of the argument above:

$ A-I = [[-1,-1],[1, 1]] = S$, consider $S$'s action on the basis $v_{\psi}, v_{\phi}$ of $V$.

$Sv_{\phi} = [0,0]^t \implies \psi([0, 0]^t) = 0$

$Sv_{\psi} = [-1, 1]^t \implies \psi([-1, 1]^t) = 0$

Since $v_{\psi}, v_{\phi}$ constitutes a basis for $V$, $range(S)=range(A-I) \subseteq null(\psi)$

So $S$ is not surjective, and thus $A$ has an eigenvalue of 1.

**Is the updated attempt above a correct proof? If not, please continue to only give hints, if possible.**

Comment: It seems that what you have written down here, in rather obstructing language dare I say, is $v^T A^T v = v^T A v = v^T v \implies Av=v$ which is simply an erroneous conclusion.

Comment: @Hyperplane I realized I was missing a major point; yes making the previous proof nonsensical. Is this better ?

Comment: This is wrong again, first of all you can't assume $\psi(w) = 1$ since the vectors could be orthogonal. It seems to me that you try to proof that not only are the eigenvalues equal, but also the eigenvectors. This is of course doomed to fail.

Comment: @Hyperplane so I caught a typo. I meant to say $\psi(w)=0$, not $T(w)=0$. The section starting with "Assume $T(v_{\psi})=w...$". Seeks to show that there exists one vector, $v \in V$, such that $\psi(v)=1$. Hence $T(v)=v$. The assumption $\psi(w)=1$ is to construct a contradiction that there cant be more than one. If $\psi(w)=0$ then $T(\psi(w))=0$ which doesn't help. I don't intend to show the eigenvectors are equal.

Comment: `I don't intend to show the eigenvectors are equal.`

But that's what you end up doing, you start with with $\psi$ being an EVec of $T'$ and you end with the conclusion that $v_\psi$ is an EVec of $T$. You should try to follow your arguments step by step on a simple example like $A=[[0,-1],[1, 2]]$ with $\psi=[1,1]$; then you will see where they fail exactly.

Comment: @Hyperplane the simple example definitely helped! I can see everything below "We seek to show..." was flawed; definitely there was a fundamental misunderstanding I had. I produced an updated attempt, based on reviewing the textbook again.